# Capybara selenium driver, hovering an element

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, rspec, cucumber, capybara

The app I'm testing has some elements hidden initially.  They will display via CSS when hovering over a separate element:

```
.thread_options{
  display: none;
}
.btn_thread_options:hover .thread_options{
  display: inline;
}
```

When you hover over the `.btn_thread_options` element, some links are displayed that I want Capybara to click on.  Attempting to click these without doing anything using `click_link "Send Response"` gives me the error:

```
Failure/Error: click_link("Send Response")
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError:
  Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Trying to use other ways of clicking it like

```
page.execute_script("$('.btn_thread_options').trigger('mouseover')")
```

Doesn't work either (same result).

Nor does clicking the item first to try to force it to be moused over:

```
page.find(".btn_thread_options").click
```

Is there any way to get this to work correctly?

Comment: Do you need display: none?  Or would setting the opacity to 0 suffice?  If not, make a step that removes that calls jquery show() on it before the click, and hide() after.

Comment: I don't think `opacity: 0` would really work since the hidden elements will submit the form and I don't want people to accidentally click on what appears to be whitespace, and end up submitting something they didn't mean to.  My work-around for now is to hide/show with jquery on mouseover and mouseout, as you mention... but it'd be nice if I could just keep it in the css :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been [added](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/965/files) to Capybara:

```
find(:css, "#menu").hover
```

Comment: Good to know! Even though you trudged this question up from 2 years ago I'll still find it helpful in the future :)

Answer (score 3):

You could try displaying the element directly rather than mousing over.

```
page.execute_script("$('.thread_options').css('display','inline')")
```

Maybe also investigate the setting of `ignore_hidden_elements`. It defaults to false, but perhaps you have it set to true.

Or instead of display none, set the margin to a large negative value.

```
/* Move the element off the screen */
.thread_options{
  margin: -9999px 0 -9999px 0;
}
/* Set the desired display margins
.btn_thread_options:hover .thread_options{
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: I upvote this because it worked for me, running execute_script wth css of 'display', 'block'

Comment: I'm not super happy with this answer because it doesn't really mimic the user behavior...but it's the only thing I could get to work right.  The other solutions would periodicaly fail.  But I'll accept it because I've got nothing better :p

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to simulate "mouse hover" using Capybara + the Selenium driver. This code is working for me:

```
module Capybara
  module Node
    class Element
      def hover
        @session.driver.browser.action.move_to(self.native).perform
      end
    end
  end
end
```